# Why doesn't L'Hôpital's rule work here?

Tags: calculus

Why doesn't L'Hôpital's rule work here? $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{x^2-x}$$
By L'Hôpital's rule I have $1$ while the limit is $0$....

Comment: By l'hipital you get 2x/(2x-1) -> 0.. Why do you say it goes to 1?

Comment: @user147985 It goes to zero only ... try again

Comment: It does work. One of the hypothesis is that the limit you're computing is undetermined if taken naively. But after you apply L'Hôpital once, you can already get the limit naively, it's not $\frac 00$ anymore, you can'use the theorem again. So $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2-x}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{2x}{2x-1}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{2}{2}\right)=1$ is wrong.

Comment: @ Git Gud Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also cancel out a factor of $x$ from the numerator and denominator to remove the discontinuity at 0.

Answer (score 15):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2x}{2x-1} = \frac{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}2x}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}2x-1} = \frac{0}{-1} = 0 \ne 1$$

**For the completeness of my answer:**
You can't use L'Hôpital the second time, since this rule demands both numerator and denominator converges to $0$ or diverges to infinity. Instead, evaluate seperatedly the limit for the numerator and denominator (arithmetic of limits) as I demonstrated above.

Comment: But when I do  L'Hôpital's rule again I have lim 2/2=1...

Comment: You can't use L'Hôpital's rule the second time (the denominator isn't $0$).

Comment: You don't have the necessary conditions to use the rule again, since the limit doesn't present an inditerminate form.

Comment: The necessary conditions are: f(x)->0, g(x)->0, and f'(x)/g'(x) has a limit. The second of these conditions is not met.

Comment: @gnasher729 well $\to0$ is one of the options. Another would be that both numerator and denominator $\to\infty$ (although you could transform this to the $\to0$ case, it's not necessary).

Comment: @AnnieOK why not include that in your answer? As it is now, it looks a bit snarky.